# What's up with these NoMachine errors?

Tags: opensuse, nomachine

I've successfully installed it on other machines, but this one is being a pain.  Throws error about not available/access disabled from the client.  Checking into it on the server side provides the following entertainment.

```
linuxts1:/usr/NX/bin # ./nxserver --status
NX> 900 Connecting to server ...
NX> 204 Authentication to NX server failed.
NX> 110 NX Server is stopped.
NX> 999 Bye.
linuxts1:/usr/NX/bin # ./nxserver --start
NX> 500 Service already running.
NX> 999 Bye.
```

So, is it running or not?  Any ideas on how to fix this interesting state?

Comment: I've now completely re-paved the box and started fresh.  Didn't get any initial install errors like I did before (for missing libraries that I had to then go find).  However, still ending up at exactly the same place with the same errors as listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/478540-nomachine-nx-opensuse-12-2-a.html

Summary:

- Change sshd_config to use "AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys2"
- HUP the sshd process
- Re-run the "nxserver --install" script
- Live happily ever after!  :-)